# Evolution of a trait in an asexual population (performance tuning)

Tags: performance-tuning, simulation, difference-equations

I just coded a simple simulation module that looks at the evolution of a continuous trait in a haploid asexually reproducing population under density dependent competition in discrete time (i.e. non-overlapping generations, using recurrence equations). What I am interested in is finding out whether evolution would always favour selecting for increased intrinsic growth rates R, perhaps eventually pushing the population to go extinct (a scenario known as "evolutionary suicide"), or if instead there would be selection for restrained growth rates, e.g. due to the fact that more selfish lineages with higher intrinsic growth rates would more often move into the chaotic regime and go extinct faster.

The module I have takes as arguments the desired fitness function (e.g. the discrete logistic model), the initial trait values of your individuals in the 1st generation, the mutation rate and the standard deviation of the normal deviation that is applied to mutants and the nr of generations to run the simulation :

```
EvolveHapl[fitnessfunc_, initpop_, mutrate_, stdev_, generations_] := 
  Module[{ndist, traitvalues, currpopsize, fastPoisson, fitnessinds, 
    numberoffspring, nrmutants, rnoise, rndelem},
   ndist = NormalDistribution[0, stdev] ;
   traitvalues = Table[{}, {generations + 1}]; (* 
   list of lists containing ind trait values in each generation *)
   traitvalues[[1]] = initpop; 
   currpopsize = Length[traitvalues[[1]]]; 
   (* fast Poisson random number generator *)
   fastPoisson = 
    Compile[{{\[Lambda], _Real}}, 
     Module[{b = 1., i, a = Exp[-\[Lambda]]}, 
      For[i = 0, b >= a, i++, b *= RandomReal[]];
      i - 1], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
     Parallelization -> True];
   Do[fitnessinds = 
     Table[fitnessfunc[traitvalues[[gen - 1]][[i]], currpopsize], {i, 
       1, currpopsize}];            (* 
    fitness of every individual in the population, 
    in mean number of offspring *)
    numberoffspring = fastPoisson[fitnessinds];            (* 
    absolute number of offspring that every individual produces *)   
    traitvalues[[gen]] = 
     Flatten[Table[
       Table[traitvalues[[gen - 1]][[i]], {j, 1, 
         numberoffspring[[i]]}], {i, 1, currpopsize}]];   (* 
    expected offspring trait values before mutation *)
    currpopsize = Length[traitvalues[[gen]]];  (* 
    new population size *)
    nrmutants = 
     RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[currpopsize, mutrate]]; (* 
    nr of offspring that should mutate *)
    rnoise = RandomReal[ndist, nrmutants]; (* 
    noise to be added to the trait values of the mutants *)
    Do[rndelem = RandomInteger[{1, currpopsize}]; 
     traitvalues[[gen]][[rndelem]] = 
      Max[traitvalues[[gen]][[rndelem]] + rnoise[[i]], 0];, {i, 1, 
      nrmutants}];, (* mutate trait values *)
    {gen, 2, generations + 1}];
   Return[traitvalues ]];
```

And to plot the resulting list of individual trait values I use

```
PlotResult[traitvalues_] := Module[{},
  generations = Length[traitvalues];
  Print["Mean phenotype at the beginning : " <> 
    ToString[Mean[traitvalues[[1]]]]];
  Print["Maximum mean phenotype at any generation : " <> 
    ToString[
     Max[Table[
        Mean[traitvalues[[i]]], {i, 1, generations}] /. {Mean[{}] -> 
         0}]]];
  Print["Mean phenotype after " <> ToString[ngens] <> 
    " generations : " <> 
    ToString[
     Mean[traitvalues[[generations]]] /. {Mean[{}] -> 
        "- (population extinct)"}]];
  Print["Final population size : " <> 
    ToString[Length[traitvalues[[generations]]]]];

  maxscaleN = 
   Max[Table[{Length[traitvalues[[i]]]}, {i, 1, generations}]];
  minscaleN = 
   Min[Table[{Length[traitvalues[[i]]]}, {i, 1, generations}]];
  maxscaleP = Max[Flatten[traitvalues]];

  GraphicsRow[{Show[
     ArrayPlot[
      Table[BinCounts[
         traitvalues[[i]], {0, maxscaleP + 0.5, 0.05}], {i, 1, 
         generations}]/
       Table[Length[traitvalues[[i]]] + 0.00001, {i, 1, generations}],
       DataRange -> {{0, maxscaleP + 0.5}, {1, generations}}, 
      DataReversed -> True], Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Phenotype frequency", "Generation"}, 
     FrameTicks -> True, AspectRatio -> 2],
    ListPlot[
     Table[{Length[traitvalues[[i]]], i}, {i, 1, generations}], 
     Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Population size", "Generation"}, 
     AspectRatio -> 2, 
     PlotRange -> {{Clip[minscaleN - 50, {0, \[Infinity]}], 
        maxscaleN + 50}, {0, generations}}]}]
   ]
```

Running it, however, is quite slow, e.g.

```
psize = 300; ngens = 5000; mutrate = 0.01; stdev = 0.05; K = 2*psize; 
f[R_, popsize_] := Max[(1 + R *(1 - popsize/K)), 0.00001];
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  traitvalues = 
    EvolveHapl[ f, RandomReal[{2.5, 2.6}, psize], mutrate, stdev, 
     ngens];]
PlotResult[traitvalues]

204.02
```

[image]

I was just wondering if there might be any obvious ways to speed up this routine in Mathematica? E.g. could I get rid of all my `Do[]` and `Table[]` loops somehow? Or could this whole routine or parts of it be compiled to speed it up? I've already replaced the Poisson number generation with a faster compiled version and used `Max[]` rather than `Clip[]` in my original post, but this hasn't improved speed as much as I had hoped it would... Or better to go to C or C++ for this kind of simple simulation?

Comment: Is there a way to condense your code / narrow down the potential bottlenecks? At the moment the question is well-posed,  but very specific,  and might get more attention if answers were to be useful for others as well.

Comment: The bottleneck is probably the PoissonDistribution used to compute numberoffspring. There are a few questions on the site about speeding up Poisson random number generation.

Comment: Well one line that is likely very inefficient is the one that reads  population = 
    Clip[offspringtraitvals + 
      RandomInteger[BinomialDistribution[1, mutrate], 
        Length[offspringtraitvals]]*
       RandomReal[ndist, 
        Length[offspringtraitvals]], {0, ∞}] - any thoughts on how to make that more efficient would be much appreciated - basically with probability mutrate it should add a bit of normally distributed noise to each list element... In any case, it's everything within the Do[] loop that I'm interested in optimising...

Comment: Optimized my code a bit by replacing the Poisson with a faster compiled version but it's still quite slow - any more thoughts for optimizations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code. On my PC it completes your example run in about 5 seconds.

I won't try to describe every change but will point out the major features. Some of the changes are stylistic rather than performance-based. This is not a criticism of your style but a reflection of the way I broke the original code down in order to understand it.

**A quick note on Map**

The most widespread change was to use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) in a lot of places where you had used `Table`. Generally in *Mathematica* whenever you find yourself using `Table` to iterate over the elements in a pre-existing list, you can usually find a more functional approach. As a simple example

```
Table[Length[traitvalues[[i]]], {i, 1, generations}]
```

can be written as

```
Length /@ traitvalues
```

Often this change will provide a performance boost, and it makes the code more readable too (once you are accustomed to the notation)

**The altered code**

The main `Do` loop in `EvolveHapl` is an iteration to compute the next generation of `traitvalues` from the previous. This can be done very neatly using [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html). My version of `EvolveHapl` just calls `NestList` to do all the work:

```
EvolveHapl[fitnessfunc_, initpop_, mutrate_, stdev_, generations_] := 
 NestList[genStep[#, fitnessfunc, mutrate, stdev] &, initpop, generations]
```

The function `genStep` computes the new population from the current one:

```
genStep[tv_, fitnessfunc_, mutrate_, stdev_] :=
 Module[{n, fitnessinds, numberoffspring, newtv},
  n = Length @ tv;
  fitnessinds = fitnessfunc[tv, n];
  numberoffspring = fastPoisson[fitnessinds];
  newtv = Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {tv, numberoffspring}];
  addNoise[newtv, mutrate, stdev]]
```

The most significant speed-up is in the calculation of `fitnessinds` - I pass the *whole* population to the fitness function. Obviously this requires that the fitness function is able to operate on a list. In your case, it can (provided we use the original version with `Clip` rather than `Max`)

`genStep` calls another function `addNoise` to do the mutations:

```
addNoise[traitvalues_, mutrate_, stdev_] :=
 Module[{tv, n, nrmutants, rnoise, rndelem},
  tv = traitvalues;
  n = Length[tv];
  nrmutants = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[n, mutrate]]; 
  rnoise = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, stdev], nrmutants];
  rndelem = RandomChoice[Range[n], nrmutants];
  tv[[rndelem]] += rnoise;
  Clip[tv, {0, ∞}]]
```

One thing to point out about `addNoise` is that I used `RandomChoice` to identify which elements to mutate. This avoids picking the same one more than once (which I assume is desirable).

I pulled `fastPoisson` out as a global function, no changes to it but I'll copy it here for completeness:

```
fastPoisson = Compile[{{λ, _Real}},
 Module[{b = 1., i, a = Exp[-λ]},
  For[i = 0, b >= a, i++, b *= RandomReal[]]; i - 1],
 RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

I made some minor changes to the `PlotResults` function, mostly converting to use `Map` where possible.

```
PlotResult[traitvalues_] :=
 Module[{generations, pop, maxscaleN, minscaleN, maxscaleP, frequencydata},
  generations = Length[traitvalues];
  Print["Mean phenotype at the beginning : " <>
    ToString[Mean[traitvalues[[1]]]]];
  Print["Maximum mean phenotype at any generation : " <>
    ToString[Max[Mean /@ traitvalues /. Mean[{}] -> 0]]];
  Print["Mean phenotype after " <> ToString[generations] <> " generations : " <>
    ToString[Mean[traitvalues[[generations]]] /. Mean[{}] -> "- (population extinct)"]];
  Print["Final population size : " <>
    ToString[Length[traitvalues[[generations]]]]];
  pop = Length /@ traitvalues;
  maxscaleN = Max[pop];
  minscaleN = Min[pop];
  maxscaleP = Max[traitvalues];
  frequencydata = (BinCounts[#, {0, maxscaleP + 0.5, 0.05}] & /@ traitvalues)/(pop + 0.00001);
  GraphicsRow[{
    Show[ArrayPlot[frequencydata, 
      DataRange -> {{0, maxscaleP + 0.5}, {1, generations}}, 
      DataReversed -> True], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True, AspectRatio -> 2,
      FrameLabel -> {"Phenotype frequency", "Generation"}],
    ListPlot[Transpose[{pop, Range[generations]}],
     Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Population size", "Generation"}, AspectRatio -> 2,
     PlotRange -> {{Clip[minscaleN - 50, {0, ∞}], maxscaleN + 50}, {0, generations}}]}]]
```

**Test**

As I mentioned I defined the fitness function using `Clip` so that it could work on a whole population at once. So the full test code is:

```
psize = 300; ngens = 5000; mutrate = 0.01; stdev = 0.05; K = 2*psize;

f[R_, popsize_] := Clip[(1 + R (1 - popsize/K)), {0.000001, ∞}];

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  traitvalues = EvolveHapl[f, RandomReal[{2.5, 2.6}, psize], mutrate, stdev, ngens];]
```

[image]

Comment: That's great - thanks so much for your hard work! And really instructive too - thanks so much!

Comment: @TomWenseleers, you're welcome, it's interesting stuff. I suspect there are further improvements that could be made, though it would probably require a fundamental rethink of the algorithm to get another order of magnitude.

Comment: Oh yes and one further question if you don't mind - what would be the best way to Parallelize this? Maybe split the trait values in tv in genStep over your cores and then Join the output? Any thoughts perhaps? (I would like to do populations of 10 000 so I guess that for that it could be worth it)

Comment: @TomWenseleers, I'm not sure, I rarely use parallelization. Try it and see, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

When building a simulation like yours you should test the performance of the individual components before incorporating them into the simulation. That is, you should know the cost of the components as well as the values they return. Here is a simple example based on your code.

You use `Clip` in a couple of places to limit values from below. That is suspect, because `Clip` is designed to confine value to an interval, i.e., from both below and above. It is likely that `Max` will be better. Let's test this theory with your fitness function.

```
initsize = 500;
With[{K = 2*initsize}, 
 fit1[R_, psize_] := Clip[(1 + R (1 - psize/K)), {0.000001, ∞}]];
 fit2[R_, psize_] := Max[(1 + R (1 - psize/K)), 0.000001]]

With[{R = 2.5, p = 1000, n = 100000},
  {First @ AbsoluteTiming[Do[fit1[R, p], n]], 
   First @ AbsoluteTiming[Do[fit2[R, p], n]]}]
```

> `{0.415949, 0.371045}`

So there is a real advantage in using `Max` rather than `Clip`. Since your simulation evaluates its fitness function thousands of times, it would pay to use `Max`.

Thorough component testing will likely reveal many more places where your code can be improved. I personally think that generating so many tables over and over again is performance area which you should investigate.

When developing a simulation that will be run many thousands of iterations, testing each piece of component code is well worth the time and effort it takes. One of *Mathematica*'s advantages for building simulations is that it makes the sort of incremental coding and unit testing for both correctness and performance much easier than traditional lower level languages such as C or C++.

Comment: Many thx - this particular replacement would lead to only a fairly small speed improvement though... The one line that is likely very inefficient is the one that reads population = Clip[offspringtraitvals + RandomInteger[BinomialDistribution[1, mutrate], Length[offspringtraitvals]]* RandomReal[ndist, Length[offspringtraitvals]], {0, ∞}] - any thoughts on how to make that more efficient would be much appreciated - basically with probability mutrate it should add a bit of normally distributed noise to each list element...

Comment: Optimized my code a bit according to your advice but it's still quite slow - any more thoughts for optimizations?

Comment: It would be better to pass the whole list into the fitness function and stick with `Clip`, IMO. Compare the timing for `fit1[Table[R, {n}], p]`

Comment: @TomWenseleers. My goal in making this answer was not to point out a big performance improvement, but to suggest an approach to developing simulations of the the sort you are interested in. I chose the particular example only because it was short and simple.

Comment: Thx - your answer was much appreciated! I kind of know the system to identify bottlenecks by looking at the timing of the different parts - the Poisson nr generation seemed one important bottleneck and that I improved a bit with this compiled function - but the performance is still not so great... So just seeking general advice for other possible optimizations...